# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline from Azure Repo always overwrites the date modified of the files. How can the date modified be preserved?

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps Build Pipeline from Azure Repo always overwrites the date modified of the files. This means that when deploying a release of say SSRS reports they will all have the current time stamp of when the files were either copied or zipped.

I have attempted the solutions offered around archiving the files and then copying the zip file but it always overwrites the date modified in the files.

The copy file task has the preserve target timestamp but the Windows machine file copy does not and so will overwrite the date modified.

[image]

Comment: At least I'm using a .zip file and dates are preserved just fine. Sounds like the question is more about how / from where are you creating that zip from.

Comment: I’m using the archive zip task. Which do you use? I archive and then publish the artifact and it overwrites. I’d tried archive then copy to remote machine and that overwrites them.

Comment: I use archive files version 2, and the timestamp of the files inside the zip is the same as what is in the disc after the build ends. Have you checked what the files in the disc look like during / after the build? At least git typically overwrites them with current time.

Comment: Yes after the build they are over stamped.  The build is literally just copying the repo files to the artifact staging directory and then a windows file copy task copies them to the server ready for the release pipeline.  I've tried not using the windows file copy task and just publishing the artifact but both methods overwrite the modified date of the file.  I'll give archive 2 a try. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out I am using Archive@2.  I do the archive then publish build artifacts and when I download the artifact and open it the individual files all have the server current time

Comment: I use the archive too after the build -- and mine works just fine as expected and keeps the timestamps when downloading the zip from build artifacts. Didn't even find any settings that could affect this.